# Showing Related Videos

Tags: video-richmedia, office-365-video-portal

I setup an asset library in SharePoint online. I have videos arranged in folders within the asset library- for example, 5 videos in Linux Administration, 4 videos in SQL. what I want is, when I open a video in SQL folder, all the other 3 videos should be shown on a side as "Related Videos".

Which is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom Jquery Library to show the same...

I had same requirement and implemented same with using Amazing Slider. You could implement thumbnail preview with video title and description and other implementation.

Also many skins and animation options available with Amazing Library.

Jquery Amazing Slider : https://amazingslider.com/examples/jquery-image-gallery/

Comment: this seems the external tool to be installed and used.any other solution available?

Comment: Its not installation package or tool You can just use the reference of the Amazing slider JS Library and utilize the same...